# Agile Whiteboard Software

Tags: agile, whiteboard

Can anyone recommend decent software that could replace a physical whiteboard, as used in Agile development?

I've had a look at http://www.brightgreenprojects.com/ but ideally we'd like something we could host ourselves. We use Jira for issue tracking, and are looking at integrating GreenHopper for project management at the moment.

The general feeling among users so far seems to be that GreenHopper is a little clunky. Is there a more straight-forward agile whiteboard software tool out there?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Best scrum tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760/best-scrum-tools) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about http://www.pivotaltracker.com/. Really nice app and it used to be free. Now they offer a 60-day trial before going paid.

Comment: +1; Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I still cannot believe why it is so difficult to find a good solutions like this.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using fancy looking [Eylean board](http://www.eylean.com/). It can match any of the process due to customisable templates. Also it has integration to other tools like TFS, TeamPulse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you use JIRA? I recently been trying out the green hopper plugin.. I liked it! But it has to do with the fact all our stories are in there. Else how about VersionOne (I found it very heavy myself). Also Thoughtworks mingle is worth a shot..

Answer (score 1):

Bright Green Projects can be installed on-site, behind your firewall.  We have done this for some of our larger clients - especially those in the public sector where cloud solutions don't sit well with security policies.

One of our clients are managing over 12,000 user stories in Bright Green with the on site version of our product.  We have also worked with their PMO to produce detailed management reports that they share with their stakeholders on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Agilo:

http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/

It is free version You can host it on You own and You can get paid consultants to help You implement this in Your organisation.